# what does `$scope.$apply() isn't high enough in the call stack` mean in this anti-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading through this document which presents anti-patterns and there is the following there:
Don't do `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()`, it means your `$scope.$apply()` isn't high enough in the call stack. Can anyone please explain me what that means?

I'm specifically interested in the `isn't high enough in the call stack` part. I know what `$$phase` and `$apply` is and why it is used. It would be great to see an example of scope being not high enough in stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call stack is the chain of calls made by a certain function, like what you can see inside the console when ther's a javascript error.
For example

```
  at Scope.$scope.openRightMenu (site/header.ctr.js:19:12)
        at Parser.functionCall (site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10567:21)
        at site/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:438:9
        at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12412:28)
        at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12510:23)
        at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (site/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:437:13)
```

This is a call stack. Now the $apply() func must be called when the entire function cycle is finished, that's why it says that it should be in the highest level of the call stack.
Because you have to be sure that every process is done in order to make a safe $apply() also because, as you know, you cannot make 2 digest cycles on the same $scope at once.

So if you have

```
func a() -> calling -> func b() //setting $scope elaborated data
func b() -> calling -> func c() //elaborating data
func c() -> calling -> func d() //getting data
```

Your $apply() call should be inside func a(), being that the highest level of your call stack.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you see if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply() somewhere in your code then is probably something wrong. Because in optimal situation you do not need to check for $scpoe.$$phase. $$phase is a property which is used by angular internally and should be not used in application code. $$phase is basicaly a boolean property which indicates that is $digest loop already progress (angular uses it to check for model updates). If you call $apply then you tell angular to start $digest phase (check for model updates). You have to do this manually only if you want to update model outside of angular code (for example on jquery plugin callbacks).

I recommend to read this great article if you want to learn angular from the inside: http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm interested in the `isn't high enough in the call stack` part. Everything else I know)